# Designing a State Machine for a UART Module

Tags: c, stm32, uart, at-command

I'm trying to work with a UART AT COMMAND 4G Module and I'm trying to design a work flow diagram as a state machine for it. 
I have a problem of

1. processing the incoming messages and sending the commands
2. How to move and change the states bewteen each other ?

Here is my initial States:

```
#define STATE_INIT 0 
#define STATE_CONNECTED 1 
#define STATE_DISCONNECTED 2 
#define STATE_RETRY_CONNECT 3 
#define STATE_FAILURE 4 
#define STATE_HTTP_POST 5
#define STATE_HTTP_GET 6 
#define STATE_HTTP_POST_RETRY 7
#define STATE_HTTP_POST_SUCCESS 8
#define STATE_HTTP_GET_RETRY 9
#define STATE_HTTP_GET_SUCCESS 10
#define STATE_CHECK_CONNECTIVITY 11
#define SIM_STATUS_ERROR 12 
#define SIM_STATUS_READY 13
#define SIM_STATUS_LOCKED 14
#define REG_STATUS_UNREGISTERED 15
#define REG_STATUS_SEARCHING 16
#define REG_STATUS_DENIED 17
#define REG_STATUS_OK 18
#define REG_STATUS_HOME 19
#define REG_STATUS_ROAMING 20
#define REG_STATUS_UNKNOWN 21
uint8_t current_state; 




void processMessage(char *msg) {

}

void sendCmd(char *cmd) {
    strcpy(UART_Out_Buffer, cmd);
    UART_Out_Cnt = strlen(cmd);
}

void Init_State(void) {

     current_state = STATE_INIT;
     sendCmd("AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,""\"IP""\",""\"A1.net""\"");
     sendCmd("AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,1,""\"ppp""\",""\"ppp@a1plus.at""\"");
     sendCmd("AT+CHTTPSOPSE=""\"ipdb-eu1.com""\",443""\"");


}
```

Here when we send a command the response should be processed.

```
void process_uart(void)
{
    uint16_t uartBufPos = 0;
    char line[UART_BUFFER_SIZE];
    line[0] = '\0';
    uint16_t linePos = 0;

    while (UART_Buffer[uartBufPos] != '\0')
    {
        if (UART_Buffer[uartBufPos] == '\n')
        {
            line[linePos] = '\0';
            processMessage(line);
            linePos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            line[linePos] = UART_Buffer[uartBufPos];
            linePos++;
            if (linePos == UART_BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                linePos = 0;
            }
        }
        uartBufPos++;
        if (uartBufPos == UART_BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            uartBufPos = 0;
        }
    }

    if (UART_Out_Cnt > 0)
    {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)UART_Out_Buffer, UART_Out_Cnt, 100);
        UART_Out_Cnt = 0;
    }
}
```

Following up with the answer: I have done this:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if (htim->Instance == TIM2)
  {
      start_processing = true;
      isSynced = true;

      if (waitreply > 1)
      {
        waitreply--;

        HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, DMA_RX_Buffer, DMA_RX_BUFFER_SIZE);

        uint16_t uartBufPos = 0;
        uint16_t linePos = 0;

        while (DMA_RX_Buffer[uartBufPos] != '\0')
        {
          if (DMA_RX_Buffer[uartBufPos] == '\n')
          {
            wait_reply = -1;
          }
          else
          {
            if (uartBufPos == DMA_RX_BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
              uartBufPos = 0;
            }

            uartBufPos++;
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

process state machine:

```
void process_state_machine()
{

    uint8_t timeout = 0;
    switch (current_state)
    {
    case STATE_INIT:
        if (wait_reply == 0)
        {
            // just entered this state, send command
            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, "AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"
                                       "\"IP"
                                       "\","
                                       "\"A1.net"
                                       "\"\r\n",
                              strlen("AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"
                                     "\"IP"
                                     "\","
                                     "\"A1.net"
                                     "\"\r\n"),
                              100);
            wait_reply = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            // reply, or timeout
            if (wait_reply == 1)
            {
                // timeout, retry
                timeout = 0; // this will re-enter this state
            }
            if (wait_reply == -1)
            {
                // analyze reply, may be change state
                wait_reply = 0;
                timeout = 1;
                current_state = STATE_CONNECTED;
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: As a comment about style, I'd use an enum rather than a set of #defines

Comment: @Skizz Thanks for the comment, Do you have other comments or an answer to my design pattern that I want to use ?

Comment: And what is your question exactly? You receive one character, you decide what you do.

Comment: It is not a simple task and my implementation is more than 2k lines long. Many modems can send responses out of order, you can run other commands even if the previous was not completed etc etc. IMO RTOS is a must for this kind of projects

Comment: @P__J__ RTOS is not an option, but I can run multiple timers... as threads.. Can you elaborate a design perspective as an answer which can give me insights?

Comment: `RTOS is not an option` good luck then. RTOS makes synchronization in order of magnitude easier

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is, but for design work, look into UML as that supports statemachine designs.

Comment: @Skizz I'm not looking for design diagrams, I'm looking for code ideas, on how to process the responses then move between states, using the above code scheme

Comment: @P__J__ Can you elaborate your solution with an RTOS as an answer ? I might consider it. Using FreeRtos for example.

Comment: @P__J__ I decided to use an RTOS. Can you answer also and show your solution using RTOS ?

Comment: Another point about style: rather than have a big switch statment based on the current state, use an array of function pointers. That way, the code becomes more manageable from a programmer perspective! Lots of small function instead of one big one (the compiler couldn't care less which one you use!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy, but you can do it with a state machine; but that state machine must have at least two levels. This is because when you send a command to the modem, it takes time; still more time is needed to wait for the response. It can be done with a single timer (a simple variable), provided that you have two circular buffers, or at least one, for the modem communication.

The state machine is called in a timely manner, say every 1/100 of second. The timer variable is called waitreply. Pseudo code is something like this:

```
statemachine:
  if (waitreply > 1): 
    waitreply--;
  read characters from modem (from circular buffer)
  is the read message complete? (ends with CR-LF?)
    no:
      (fall to the rest of the routine)

    yes:
      is this out-of-band data?
        yes:
          put it aside and ignore
        no:
          waitreply = -1;
```

The remaining part is a switch statement, one case for every state. Every state is divided in two:

```
case SEND_AT:
  if (waitreply == 0) {
    // just entered this state, send command
    send command
    waitreply = some_timeout
  } else {
    // reply, or timeout
    if (waitreply == 1) {
      // timeout, retry
      waitreply = 0;  // this will re-enter this state
    }
    if (waitreply == -1) {
      // analyze reply, may be change state
      waitreply = 0;
      STATE = SEND_ATI;
    }
  }
  break;
```

This is just an idea, hope it helps in some way.

===== EDIT after comments =====

As seen in the code above, the waitreply variable implements a second-level state machine. If waitreply==0, no transaction is in progress: a command can be sent; if ==-1, then a reply from the modem is ready to be read by the current "state"; otherwise, the state machine is just waiting. Thus, the test for (waitreply > 0) could be moved to the beginning of the function and, if satisfied, simply exit the function prematurely. But this doesn't seem a big improvement.

About the questions from the OP:

1. Yes, a timer calls the state machine every 1/100 of second. The variable waitreply is initialized to zero.
2. There is no "thread", this is a simple routine called from the main

A C program skeleton is as follow:

```
int waitreply;
enum blahblah state;
void statemachine(void);

void main(void) {
  waitreply = 0;    // already zeroed by C runtime
  state=ST_SENDAT;  // see if the modem is alive
  do {
    if (timer_expired) {
      // 1/100 sec elapsed
      statemachine();
      start_timer();
    }
  }
}


void statemachine(void) {
  // prologue... modem_replay will contain the reply from modem
  switch (state) {
    case ST_SENDAT:
      if (waitreply == 0) {
        // just entered this state, send command
        send_to_modem("AT" CR LF);
        waitreply = 200;   // 2 seconds
      } else {
        // reply, or timeout
        if (waitreply == 1) {
          // timeout, retry
          waitreply = 0;  // this will re-enter this state
        }
        if (waitreply == -1) {
          // analyze reply, may be change state
          waitreply = 0;
          if (0 == strcmp(modem_reply, "OK"))
              STATE = SEND_ATI;   // another state, to get info from modem
              // else will re-enter this same state, for ever
        }
      }
      break;
  }  // end of switch
} // func statemachine
```

I repeat, this is just an idea which grants fine control, but nothing more.

Comment: Thanks so much, so how would I use your idea into my code ? first, should I initiate a timer that runs 1/100 seconds, and initiate wait_reply to some value ? can you add more pseudo code please, your idea is really nice

Comment: another question, the switch part, is it running in the timer thread part or in the main loop ?

Comment: I need please an example of how to use your pseudcode

Comment: Can you check the post, I added an example of your idea... can you check it

Comment: you also didn't elaborate about the timeout variable

Comment: I modified the post, with implementation of your answer...but have some issues with time_out variable, would you review it please